# How to update thousands of rows in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

Im trying to update 100.000 rows in my database, the following code should do that but I always get an error :

> Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Because it is an update I don't need the result and just want to get rid of them. The $count variable is used so that my database gets chunks of updates instead of one big update. (One big update is not working because of some limitations of the database).

I tried a lot of different things like mysqli_free_result and so on... nothing worked.

```
    global $mysqliObject;

    $count = 0;    
    $statement = "";

    foreach ($songsArray as $song) {

        $id = $song->getId();
        $treepath = $song->getTreepath();

        $statement = $statement."UPDATE songs SET treepath='".$treepath."' WHERE id=".$id."; ";
        $count++;

        if ($count > 10000){

            $result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqliObject, $statement);

            if(!$result) {
                 die('<br/><br/>Error1: ' . mysqli_error($mysqliObject));    
            }



            $count = 0;

            $statement = ""; 
        }


    }
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Comment: This is an absolutely ideal candidate for prepared statements. They will be much easier to use and much more efficient. I personally never use `_multi_query()`, it is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I have never used prepared statements, could you post an answer with a prepared statement, instead of mine

Comment: @SebastianOberste-Vorth What type of data is `$treepath`? Is it a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way...

Since this is not a production server - the fastest way to update 100k rows is by deleting all of them and inserting 100k from scratch with the new calculated values. It seems a little bit odd to delete everything and insert everything instead of updating but it is WAYYY faster.

Before: hours Now: seconds!

Comment: If it was taking hours before, I'd suggest that your problem is actually indexing. 100K rows is not very many in the grand scheme of things, with a properly set up primary key (and using the primary key to locate the record that needs to be updated) this should take no more than a couple of seconds, even on a busy server.

Comment: This works because you are deleting **all** rows and effective recreating the table, so the physical I/O is optimised -- especially if you've disabled the indices during the bulk insert.  As I said above if the table contained 1M rows and you where deleting then reinserting 10%, you'd have a different story.

Answer (score 4):

Using a prepared query *will* reduce the CPU load in the mysqld process as DaveRandom and StevenVI suggest.  However in this case I doubt that using prepared queries will materially impact your runtime.  The challenge that you have is that you are attempting to update 100K rows in the `songs` table and this is going to involve a lot of physical I/O on your physical disk subsystem.  It is these physical delays (say ~10 mSec per PIO) that will dominate runtimes.  Factors such as what is contained in each row, how many indexes are you using on the table (especially those that involve treepath) will all blend into this mix.

The actual CPU costs of preparing a simple statement like

> `UPDATE songs SET treepath="some treepath" WHERE id=12345;`

will be lost in this overall physical I/O delay, and the relative size of this will materially depend on the nature of the physical subsystem where you are storing your data: a single SATA disk; SSD; some NAS with large caches and SSD support ...

You need to rethink your overall strategy here, especially if you are also using the `songs` table at the same time as an resource for interactive requests through a web front-end.  Updating 100K rows is going to take some time -- less if you are updating 100K out of 100K in storage order since this will be more aligned to the MYD organisation and the write-though caching will be better; more if you are update 100K rows in random order out of 1M rows, where the number of PIOs will be a lot more.

When you are doing this, the overall performance of your D/B is going to degrade badly.

- Do you want to minimise impact on parallel use of your DB or are you just trying to do this as dedicated batch operation with other services offline?
- Is your goal to minimise the total elapsed time or to keep it reasonable short subject to some overall impact constrain, or even just to complete without dying.

I suggest that you've got two sensible approaches: (i) do this as a proper batch activity with the D/B offline to other services.  In this case you probably want to take out a lock on the table, and bracket the updates with ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE/ENABLE KEYS.  (ii) do this as a trickle update with far smaller update sets and a delay between each set to allow the D/B to flush to disk.

Whatever, I'd drop the batch size.  The multi_query essentially optimises RPC over heads involved in calling the out-of-process mysqld.  A batch of 10 say cuts this by 90%.  You've got diminishing returns after this -- especially saying the updates will be physical I/O intensive.

Comment: +1 now that's an answer and a half. What sort of difference does the underlying storage engine make to this? MEMORY completely eliminates the disk I/O issue so prepared statements will give a noticeable performance increase(?), but to take the common real-world question - MyISAM vs InnoDB - what kind of a difference would this make to the disk I/O activity? I'm thinking MyISAM will be worse for performance in a parallel use scenario because of table-level locking during the update(?), but in a dedicated batch job, which would be quicker?

Comment: yup, and the other killer for MyISAM is that it doesn't do data caching, so any updates get immediately written back to the MYD file -- albeit through the VFAT write-through mechanism on \*nix.  Yes, the batch job will take less time, but what if the OP doesn't want to take down his online service during a long update?  In general InnoDB is recommended for update intensive tables.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I ll +1 all of you guys, I learned a lot... in the end I found another simple way to do it, because I can do it "offline" (DROP + INSERT)

Comment: @SebastianOberste-Vorth, if you are going to do it offline by doing a complete recreate, then **TRUNCATE** the table, disable keys, do the bulk insert, reenable keys and optimize the table :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code using prepared statements:

```
// Create a prepared statement
$query = "
  UPDATE `songs`
  SET `treepath` = ?
  WHERE `id` = ?
";
$stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqliObject']->prepare($query); // Global variables = bad

// Loop over the array
foreach ($songsArray as $key => $song) {

  // Get data about this song
  $id = $song->getId();
  $treepath = $song->getTreepath();

  // Bind data to the statement
  $stmt->bind_param('si', $treepath, $id);

  // Execute the statement
  $stmt->execute();

  // Check for errors
  if ($stmt->errno) {
    echo '<br/><br/>Error: Key ' . $key . ': ' . $stmt->error;
    break;
  } else if ($stmt->affected_rows < 1) {
    echo '<br/><br/>Warning: No rows affected by object at key ' . $key;
  }

  // Reset the statment
  $stmt->reset();

}

// We're done, close the statement
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: But isn't this code updating the database 100.000 times? I have done a similar thing without prepared statements, and this took forever, thats why I tried multi_query, which is unfortunately giving me my error

Comment: @SebastianOberste-Vorth Because of the way in which prepared statements work, there is actually less work to do behind the scenes here. Because the statement is being prepares, each execution only sends the *data* to the server, not the whole SQL statement. The statement is only parsed once (when calling `prepare()`) and in the long run this will be much faster and more efficient,

Comment: Read the PHP pages about prepared statements. The logic is condensed (for want of a better explanation).

Comment: I just tested your code against my previous code (One Update for each song without the prepared statements). They are running exactly the same time! :(

Comment: @SebastianOberste-Vorth I am surprised it's not a little faster, but if that's the case I'm also guessing it doesn't take very long - how long is it taking to execute? How are you collecting the data for the operations? It may be that you can make it appear to be faster by using AJAX etc.

Comment: What role does the $key variable play? When is it set? Why don't we just use foreach ($songsArray as $song)?

Comment: @SebastianOberste-Vorth The only point of `$key` is so that you can see the position in the input array at which errors occur. If you don't want this information, you can get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
  $link = mysqli_connect('host');
  if ( $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE songs SET treepath=? WHERE id=?") ) {

    foreach ($songsArray as $song) {

        $id = $song->getId();
        $treepath = $song->getTreepath();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $treepath); // Assuming it's a string...
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  }
  mysqli_close($link);
```

Or of course you normal mysql_query's but enclosed in a transaction.

Comment: Like the comment above - is this code updating the database 100.000 times? My code has to execute fast...

Comment: If the songsarray is 100.000 items big, yes it will be. But I'd advise strongly against such huge arrays in PHP. Your initial code is updating the database 100k times too. But slower as the SQL server has to parse each query over and again. Here you parse it once, and just send new values to work with.

Comment: For my computation of new treepaths I need all entries of my database. I store them at the beginning of the script and use them all the time - and in the end for updating, too. What would be a better solution to not storing all entries and still be able to calculate means and so on over all entries in the db? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to lock the table and disable the keys before executing multiple updates.
This would avoid that the database engine stops (at least in my case of 300,000 row update).

```
LOCK TABLES `TBL_RAW_DATA` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `TBL_RAW_DATA` DISABLE KEYS */;

UPDATE TBL_RAW_DATA SET CREATION_DATE = ADDTIME(CREATION_DATE,'01:00:00') WHERE ID_DATA >= 1359711;

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `TBL_RAW_DATA` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```